# spring.jackson.date-format property does not work properly for the date serialization with @Temporal annotation

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson, application.properties

I have the following property in application.properties file:

```
spring.jackson.date-format=yyyy-MMM-dd
```

There is object definition to be serialized:

```
public class InjuryDTO {

private Long id;

private String kindOfInjury;

private String muscle;

private String side;

private Integer outOfTraining;

private Date injuryDate;

private Long athleteId;

// getters and setters are omitted for brevity }
```

This is class from which InjuryDTO object is originally created:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "INJURY")
public class Injury {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "INJURY_ID")
private Long id;

@Column(name = "KIND_OF_INJURY")
private String kindOfInjury;

@Column(name = "MUSCLE")
private String muscle;

@Column(name = "SIDE")
private String side;

@Column(name = "OUT_OF_TRAINING")
private Integer outOfTraining;

@Temporal(value = TemporalType.DATE)
@Column(name = "INJURY_DATE")
private Date injuryDate;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "ATHLETE_ID")
@JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)
private Athlete athlete;

// get,set-ters are removed for brevity 
}
```

So, if the deserialization of this JSON property happens:

```
"injuryDate":"2018-Jun-02"
```

Jackson accepts this string and transforms it to the corresponding java.util.Date object, but when serialization happens with no commented `@Temporal(value = TemporalType.DATE)` annotation then server gets back the following JSON property: `"injuryDate":"2018-06-02"`.

**Question is**: Why @Temporal annotation affects the actual representation of the date property in JSON?

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
 @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
 @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
 @Column(name="INJURY_DATE")
 private Date injuryDate;
```